# How do you cout a custom data table in c++

Tags: c++11

I am trying to cout a table that looks like this. I have two multimaps and i would like to put all the data from one map in col1 and all the data from the other map in col2.

```
Col 1                       Col 2
------------------------------------------
item1                      item4
item2                      item9
item5                      item3
                           item6
```

```cpp
    multimap <int, string> :: iterator col1;
        for (col1 = map1.begin(); col1 != map1.end(); ++col1)
        {
            cout << col1->name << '\n';
        }
    multimap <int, string> :: iterator col2;
    for (col2 = map2.begin(); col2 != map2.end(); ++col2)
        {
            cout << col2->name << '\n';
        }
```

Comment: What is the main issue you are facing? Are you having problems formatting the columns or iterating through containers of different sizes? Please post the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code has *two consecutive* loops, so that the data contained in `map2` will be printed only *after* the data in `map1`.

To arrange the output in two columns, the data from each map must be printed in the *same row*. Be carefull not to access each container out of bounds.

The following is just an example

```
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::multimap <int, std::string> map1 {
        {1, "Alpha"}, {2, "Beta"}
    };
    std::multimap <int, std::string> map2 {
        {2, "Gamma"}, {2, "Delta"}, {3, "Rho"}
    };
    auto col1 = map1.cbegin();
    auto col2 = map2.cbegin();

    // I'm using a lambda just not to repeat code.
    auto show = [](std::ostream& os, auto& it, auto last) -> std::ostream& {
        if ( it != last)
        { 
            os << std::setw(4) << std::right << it->first << "  "
               << std::setw(10) << std::left << it->second;
            ++it;  // <- Advance only when an element is printed. 
        }          
        else
        {
            os << std::setw(16) << "";
        }
        return os;    
    };
    
    while ( not (col1 == map1.cend() and col2 == map2.cend()) )
    {
        show(std::cout, col1, map1.cend()) << "    ";
        show(std::cout, col2, map2.cend()) << '\n';
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
   1  Alpha            2  Gamma     
   2  Beta             2  Delta     
                       3  Rho
```